# Swagger shows extra parameters in request body

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

We are using springfox-swagger-ui and springfox-swagger2 of version 2.7.0.

A post api has the following signature :

```
@ApiOperation("Edits information about employees")
@PostMapping(path = "/employee/edit", headers = EndPoints.VERSION_1)
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Data mismatch"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid data passed")
})
public ResponseEntity<Employee> manageEmployee(
        @RequestHeader("employeeId") final String iEmployeeId,
        @RequestBody(required = true) @Valid final Employee iEmployee)
```

The object employee is:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7315844547195801413L;

    private String employeeName;
    private Long employeeId;
    private @Valid @NotNull List<Address> addresses;

    // getter and setter methods

    @Validated
    public static class Address implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6748945632164495934L;

        private String addressId;

        @ValidAddress
        private String addressName;

        //getter and setter methods
    }
}
```

But the swagger shows the request body as :

```
{
 "addresses": {
   "addressId": "string",
   "addressName": "string",
   "permanentAddress": [
      {
        "addressId": "string",
        "addressName": "string"
      }
   ]
  },
 "employeeName": "string",
 "employeeId": 0
}
```

The object permanentAddress is not present in my code.
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Before questioning why permantnAddress, I think it's more important to find out why addresses is an object of addressId, addressName, and a list of Address. Something doesn't look right in the JSON.

The Employee object looks like:

```
{
  addresses: [
    addressId: "string",
    addressName: "string"
  ],
  employeeName: "string",
  employeeId: 0
}
```

permanentAddress is the correct object for List addresses